# Wrong output while converting epoch time to human format date and time?

Tags: java, date

I am newbie in Java. I am trying to convert epoch time human format time. I refereed many web site, every one mentioned below steps but I am getting wrong output.

```
String format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(format);
String expDate=dateFormat.format(new Date(1478017281));
System.out.println(expDate);
```

**System Output :**

```
18/01/1970 08:03:37
```

**Expected Output:**

```
01/11/2016 21:51:21
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It should be milliseconds not seconds

Answer (score 4):

The Date constructor takes a long argument which is supposed to be the time in milliseconds, not seconds. Add 3 0's at the end of it and it will print the expected result.

Comment: Don't forget the `L`.

Comment: @shmosel : compiler will complain about missing L, so it's hard to forget about it.

Comment: where can I use `L` ?

Comment: @rkosegi So much for that ;)

Comment: @Kalanidhi : instead of `new Date(1478017281)` use `new Date(1478017281000L)`

Comment: Yeah working , Can you please explain what is the use of `L` ?

Comment: @Kalanidhi : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1  `An integer literal is of type long if it is suffixed with an ASCII letter L or l (ell); otherwise it is of type int (§4.2.1)`

Comment: @rkosegi,Thanks , you are saved may day :)-

Comment: @Kalanidhi I highly recommend studying sections of the Oracle Tutorial as you progress in learning Java. First time you use a primitive number, go read that section. First time you work with date-time read [that section of the tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html) and learn that **you are using the wrong date-time classes**, now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes.